# Static data table issues while executing multiple process

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have a console application .exe which is spawn by 50+ processes, which will insert 10000 of records into a database by passing different argument in to it, in order to run in parallel.

In that exe, I am using one static data table which stores some values initially, and all the processes use this data table to fetch certain values. The issue now I am facing is once or twice per week, a value becomes null from data table. Later if I rerun the exe, I will get proper values.

Any idea what the reason of this issue might be? I increased connection pool in `app.config` to 500. Is it bad to use static data table while process is executing 50 plus times?

In the following code, sometimes `regioncodevalue` will become null, but after rerun, I will get values

```
static DataTable dtZone = all.CreateDataTableFromQuery("O_ZONE", geozonesql, ref ErrorMessage, true);

string regioncodevalue = GetRegionCodeFromGeoZoneCode(geo_zone_code);

private static string GetRegionCodeFromGeoZoneCode(string geo_zone_fromcell)
{
    string region_code = "";

    try
    {
        geo_zone_fromcell = geo_zone_fromcell.Replace(" ", "");

        if (dtZone .Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var dValue = from row in dtZone .AsEnumerable()
                         where row.Field<string>("GEO_ZONE_CODE") == "" + geo_zone_fromcell + ""
                         select row.Field<string>("REGION_CODE");
            region_code = dValue.First();

            return region_code;
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex.Message);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the timing. If your datatable is being populated while you're querying the geo codes, some entries might be null since the population has not finished yet. You might be better of filling it first and only then start the querying in order to make sure, you're datatable is ready.

Comment: datatble fill at start,like when appdomain loads